# Did a clean build to fix 'RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity' but get a blank screen now

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I was getting this error '*Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo*' and saw someone say do a clean solution and it will work. I did the clean build and it runs but only gives me a [blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzIlt.jpg). It's not giving me any errors so I'm also struggling to even search the problem.

I'm building my app in Visual Studio with Xamarin and using an azure server/database.

Any ideas on why this could happen? I can post code if you need it, not sure what code you could need since there's a nice bit.

Edit: Here's the code for my main activity as I think if there's a problem it should be here

```
namespace ProEventsApp
{
[Activity(Label = "ProEventsApp", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    private Button btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        btnSignIn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignIn);
        btnSignIn.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
        {
            //Pull up dialog
            StartActivity(typeof(Dialog_SignIn));


            //signUpDialog.ZOnSignUpComplete += SignUpDialog_zOnSignUpComplete;
        };

        btnSignUp = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignUp);
        btnSignUp.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
        {
            //Pull up dialog
            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            Dialog_SignUp signUpDialog = new Dialog_SignUp();
            signUpDialog.Show(transaction, "Dialog Fragment");

            //signUpDialog.ZOnSignUpComplete += SignUpDialog_zOnSignUpComplete;
        };

    }

   /* private void SignUpDialog_zOnSignUpComplete(object sender, OnSignUpEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thead = new Thread(ActLikeARequest);
        thead.Start();
    }

    private void ActLikeARequest()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }*/
}
```

Edit 2: [Here's the log](https://pastebin.com/QiMAZSPE)

[Main AXML](https://pastebin.com/pDEUYgSY)

Edit 3: Version 15.5.4

Comment: Can you please include the full error? Secondly, please include your version information.

Comment: @JonDouglas I put the log in the description there and I looking for where the version is atm

Comment: Where is the `Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo` in the log you posted?

Comment: I did a clean build and it went away, ever since the clean build, it runs but gives me that blank screen

Comment: What's included in your Main layout file?

Comment: The axml file or activity?

Comment: The AXML / XML.

Comment: Problem solved, have a runtime exception now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two Activities with this line in it '**[Activity(Label = "ProEventsApp", MainLauncher = true)]**'

I changed it to be '**[Activity(Label = "ProEventsApp")**

My bad